# SoapUI Assertion failed to validate Double to Int

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertion

I have property which its value is 21.0 which sometimes i need to assert to be 21.0 and sometimes to be 21

I have `xpath: //Results/ResultSet/Row[@rowNumber="1"]/KI_VALUE`
I want my result to show:

```
<KI_VALUE>21</KI_VALUE>
```

my expected result: `${#TestCase#VALUE1}` which give me 21.0. how can i round it to be 21? when i tried to put function of round it refer to it as it was part of string output.

Comment: meitale, please check the answer to see if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

XPath supports `round()`. Add it to your expression:

```
round(//Results/ResultSet/Row[@rowNumber="1"]/KI_VALUE)
```

See: [XPath Specification, 4.4 Number Functions, Function round](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-round)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use xpath's `starts-with` function, so that it can match all the starting value.

SoapUI properties are read as String values, so can't use `round` function.

**XPath Assertion way:**

Define XPath Assertion as:

```
starts-with(//Results/ResultSet/Row[@rowNumber="1"]/KI_VALUE, ${#TestCase#VALUE1})
```

And use expected value as `true`

If you want to match it using numbers, then you can use `Script Assertion` so that it can be compared mathematically.

**Script Assertion way:**

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
def xml = new XmlHolder(context.response)
//change the xpath as per the need
def responseValue = xml.getNodeValue("//Results/ResultSet/Row[@rowNumber="1"]/KI_VALUE") as Double
//change the property name as needed
def expectedValue = context.testCase.getPropertyValue('VALUE1') as Double

assert expectedValue == responseValue, "Both actual and expected KI_VALUE are not matching"
```